# Monkey patching in golang fails when I remove fmt.Println()

Tags: unit-testing, go, monkeypatching

While writing a test I have to patch a method in order to check that it is called, this is my code:

```
import "fmt"

type myStruct struct {}

func (myObject *myStruct) firstMethod() {
    myObject.SecondMethod()
}
func (myObject *myStruct) SecondMethod() {
    fmt.Println("Inside the original SecondMethod") //test fails if I remove this
}
```

and this is the test:

```
import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
    "github.com/bouk/monkey"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "fmt"
)
func TestThatSecondMethodIsCalled(t *testing.T) {
    myObject := &myStruct{}

    wasCalled := false
    monkey.PatchInstanceMethod(
        reflect.TypeOf(myObject),
        "SecondMethod",
        func(*myStruct) {
            fmt.Println("Inside the replacement of SecondMethod")
            wasCalled = true
        },
    )

    myObject.firstMethod()
    assert.True(t, wasCalled)
}
```

If I run the test like this, it will pass, but if I remove the `fmt.Println()` from SecondMethod, then the test fails (the test uses the original body of the method, not the patched one).

Also if I use debugging from Goland, the test passes even if SecondMethod has an empty body.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider a test reliable if you're using monkey patching like this. If you read that project's README you'll see `Monkey sometimes fails to patch a function if inlining is enabled` -- also note `Monkey is not threadsafe. Or any kind of safe.`. It's a neat experiment but there have to be better, safer ways to do what you want.

Comment: `github.com/bouk/monkey` relies on reverse-engineering a code generation pattern which may or may not exist: Monkey Patching in Go : https://bou.ke/blog/monkey-patching-in-go/  As you have discovered, it's very fragile. Worse, it can give false positives and false negatives when testing and wrong results when executing.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by compiler's inline optimize, add `-gcflags="-N -I"` will disable it.